# Can Java Interface be Modified after Release

Tags: java, interface

When I was working with COM, one of the rules was that once an interface is created, its signature can never be modified. I am not sure if this is true with Java interface. I don't think it is a good idea to change the signature of any method or delete a method, but what about adding a new method?

Comment: That really depends on what you plan to do with this interface. A Java interface that is used by you, in a simple project that isn't shared or otherwise exposed, can be changed as much as you want. Implementing classes need to be adopted - obviously. If you "share" that interface (for some definition of "share"... webservices, etc.) changing an interface can cause issues. What is your bigger context here?

Comment: I am not entirely sure that your understanding of `interface` matches with mine and what do you mean with `Release`? Could you provide an example to illustrate what you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java 7 and below, adding a new method to an interface will require every class implementing it to also implement it.

In Java 8 and above, if you add a `default` method, it will *not* require you to do that.

The main thing to note is that the interface is basically an API.  If you add a new method to the API and there are concrete implementations claiming to adhere to the API, then it *should* be the case that the new methods are concretely implemented.

This also gives one pause when adding a new method; if you *have* to do it, you have to be sure that it's worth going through all other implementors to add it in.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a new method to an interface that has already been implemented by various libraries will have a single problem: anyone calling the new method on an old implementation will get an exception. Note that loading the class will work fine, and calling old methods will work fine too.

Of course, the classes implementing the interface will also not compile anymore if they start implementing the new version of your interface: they will be forced to implement the additional methods.

That doesn't mean it's a good idea, though. It should be avoided if you can. Since Java 8, default methods in interfaces can help providing a default implementation, if possible, for new methods. That allows old implementations to stay compatible with the new interface.

All the above is written in the context of writing an API that is implemented and used by external projects, not under your control or not released at the same time as the new interface. If the interface is only used in your own project, and all its implementations are thus under your control, modifying the interface and its implementations is not a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected, modifying an interface [that's intended for third-party implementations] after a release is a risky practice - if you change an interface, you will break all the currently existing implementations, or at the very least, force the implementors to modify their implementations accordingly.

Adding a method is also problematic - as you'll be adding a method that the implementations do not have, you will still be breaking these implementations, as now they will no longer implement the said interface.

Java 8 offers a partial solution for this in the form of [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html), which allow you to add new methods with a default implementation to your interfaces. This way, an implementation that does not implement the new method will just inherit the default implementation instead of breaking compilation. E.g., consider this old interface:

```
public interface Person {
    String getFirstName();
    String getLastName();
}
```

Prior to Java 8, adding a new `getFullName()` method would just break old implementations. However, in Java 8, you could now offer a default implementation:

```
public interface Person {
    String getFirstName();
    String getLastName();

    // New method added in version 2:
    default String getFullName() {
        return getFirstName() + " " + getLastName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to add new method in interface than its not a good idea  to change interface as there can be many classes in which you need to add that method but

**interface can extend another interface and in new interface you can add your new method**

check this code :

```
interface oldInterface{
  public void oldInterfaceMethod();
}

interface newInterface extends oldInterface{
  public void newInterfaceMethod();
}


class OldInterfaceImplementor implements oldInterface {

  @Override
  public void oldInterfaceMethod() {
  }
}

class NewInterfaceImplementor implements newInterface{

  @Override
  public void oldInterfaceMethod() {
  }

  @Override
  public void newInterfaceMethod() {
  }

}
```